# How to break out of using block from inside IDisposable class

Tags: c#, using, idisposable

I got a disposable class with following constructor:

```
 public MyClass(bool allowed){
    if(allowed) return;
    else { // leave outer using }
}
```

And it is used like this

```
using (new MyClass(false))
{
   DoSomething();
}
```

Or like following

```
using (new MyClass(true))
{
   DoSomething();
}
```

How to achieve that only the one called with (true) will execute the block (aka DoSomething()) and if it is called with (false) it will not execute the block?

Comment: 1. Pass the boolean value into the `DoSomething` method. 2. Store it at class level and check inside `DoSomething`. 3. Wrap the entire `using` block in an `if` check. There's a lot of options here, too broad really. This code feels a little smelly.

Comment: Why is MyClass disposable in the first place? Why can't you make it not implement IDisposable and just return a boolean, and just use an if statement?

Comment: `if (! allowed) throw new Something();`

Comment: throw an exception inside the constructor

Comment: Even if you can do it, should you? At a casual glance, how do you think the code will read to another dev (or you in about 2 weeks time)? If it's non-obvious, then you shouldn't consider it.

Comment: MyClass is actually a validator.

Comment: That doesn't help us, the question is still too opinion based, broad and unclear.

Comment: "... is a validator" doesn't change anything. A `using() {}` block just isn't designed for flow control.

Comment: @Best_Where_Gives: well, then provide a `Validate` method and check there the `bool` property and add the logic. Also, why a validator needs to implement `IDisposable`? Use it only if you use unmanaged resources. Not as replacement for your business logic.

Answer (score 1):

Since the previous answer was not sufficient, I would suggest adding a public property to MyClass which can be used to get the boolean value and check against that in the using statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not base on the value boolean

```
var b = true;// or false
using (new MyClass(b))
{
    if(b)
        DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Because the validation MUST be inside MyClass

Comment: @Best_Where_Gives: Why? If `DoSomething` was part of `MyClass`(which you not even use), then you could add the logic there.